# React local storage sometimes won't save objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui, next.js

I have this component which saving objects are working from time to time without reliability. Sometimes when I inject 2 of the same component the local storage object gets overridden. Can you guess what's the problem is? I get the same problem in another component when replacing radio button with autocomplete instead from material UI.

Thanks in advance :)

```js
function SingleOption({ data }: QuestionProps) {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Answers') || '[]')
  );
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Time') || '[]')
  );

  const [final, setFinal] = useState(0);
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  let end: number = 0;

  const index = tasks.findIndex((task: any) => task.id === data.id);
  const [values, setValues] = useState<State>({
    id: data.id,
    SingleOption:
      tasks.length > 0 && index != -1 ? tasks[index].SingleOption : '',
  });

  const handleAddTask = () => {
    const index = tasks.findIndex((task: any) => task.id === data.id);
    if (index === -1) {
      setTasks([...tasks, values]);
      setTimer([...timer, final]);
    } else {
      let dataEdit = [...tasks];
      dataEdit[index] = values;
      setTasks(dataEdit);
      let end = new Date().getTime();
      setFinal(end - start);
      let timerEdit = [...timer];
      timerEdit[index] = final;
      setTimer(timerEdit);
    }
  };
  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
    end = new Date().getTime();
    setFinal((end - start) / 1000);

    handleAddTask();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('Answers', JSON.stringify(tasks));
      window.localStorage.setItem('Time', JSON.stringify(timer));
    };
  }, [values]);
  return (
    <>
      {data ? (
        <Grid css={singleOptionCss}>
          <CardHeader title={data.text} subheader={data.description} />
          <RadioGroup
            row
            aria-label="answer"
            css={genderRadioGroupCss}
            // onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {data.answerType != QuestionsTypes.yesNo ? (
              data.answers.map(item => (
                <div key={item.label}>
                  <Radio
                    key={values.id + values.SingleOption}
                    name="SingleOption"
                    value={item.value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    checked={values.SingleOption === item.label ? true : false}
                    icon={<span css={labelCss(false)}>{item.label}</span>}
                    checkedIcon={<span css={labelCss(true)}>{item.label}</span>}
                  />
                </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <div>
                <Radio
                  name="SingleOption"
                  value="true"
                  checked={values.SingleOption === 'true' ? true : false}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  icon={<span css={labelCss(false)}>Yes</span>}
                  checkedIcon={<span css={labelCss(true)}>Yes</span>}
                />
                <Radio
                  name="SingleOption"
                  value="false"
                  checked={values.SingleOption === 'false' ? true : false}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  icon={<span css={labelCss(false)}>No</span>}
                  checkedIcon={<span css={labelCss(true)}>No</span>}
                />
              </div>
            )}
          </RadioGroup>
        </Grid>
      ) : (
        <Grid css={singleOptionCss}>
          <CircularProgress />
        </Grid>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: check the handleChange,maybe this function was called multiple time,when you click one Radio component